# phonegap geo uri association

Tags: javascript, cordova, associations, geo

I am developing a phonegap application using phonegap build (therefore ALL in pure js and html, no native languages).

In my page, i have some geo uri links (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geo_URI ) that are cliccable (they represent coordinates of markers in a map).

Now, if the mobile device has installed and associated with this type of files an app (usually a gps navigator or the like), they open and launch the associated application as they should.

My issue is that I don't want to show the clickable link (the button appears in the infowdindow of the marker) if the device has no app capable to open them.

In native android code, you have the query-intent command for this. Does anyone know how to verify this in pure phonegap js?

Ty!

D.

I have been asked for code: The only code that is relevant here is the following, which computes the html code to embed in the infowindow of the marker:

```
    var computePathString=<a href='geo:"+area['marker']['position'].lat()+",
    "+area['marker']['position'].lng()+"'>Route</a>;
```

Which translates to the following html:

```
    <a href='geo:45.557,9.1523'>Route</a>
```

Which works great on click IFF the device has an associated app (usually a gps navigator), but else does nothing on click. I need to achieve something similar to the query intents of android:

```
   PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
   List<ResolveInfo> activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
   boolean isIntentSafe = activities.size() > 0;
```

only, in native phonegap js.

Comment: Can you possibly post here relevant parts of the code you already have (if any)?

Comment: Done, but it's not really a code based problem, it's just that i don't know what is the equivalent of the query intent.

Comment: Have you done much work with JS before? Because that first bit of code you posted isn't a valid string, which could be where your code is breaking. Are you open to using jQuery? jQuery makes it stupid simple to create html elements dynamically.

Comment: Guys, you're not really helping him :) The problem (that I also have) is: can you detect in Javascript whether there's an app registered to handle a geo: URI. I think the answer is no, based on some searching, but I'm still looking.